# how to extract particular value in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

how to extract  this string using oracle sql or regex..

```
input : 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, **ml_orig as cde_value**, date_key, desc'
output: 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, **cde_value**, date_key, desc'
```

I want to output cde_val and replace any word before it until the previous column separated by "," and want to keep the other string intact after that.

before cde_value until the previous column, seprated by ",".

Comment: all columns before cde until cde intact as cde???

Comment: sample iniput output required

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WITH src AS (
  SELECT 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, ml_orig as cde_value, date_key, desc'' output: ''run_id, src_key, cd_key, cde_value, date_key, desc' X
  FROM dual
)
SELECT x, regexp_replace( x, '(.*,)[^,]+as cde_value(.*)', '\1replacment\2') xx
FROM src
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fa35/2

```
before| run_id, src_key, cd_key, ml_orig as cde_value, date_key, desc' output: 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, cde_value, date_key, desc |
after | run_id, src_key, cd_key,replacment, date_key, desc' output: 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, cde_value, date_key, desc |
```

Comment: Thanks .. how can i make the lookup of as cde_value as case insensitive,

Comment: this regex wouldn't handle the start of string and as it stands works only for a specific value.

Comment: hi krokodilko, Can you please let me know how can i do if the string at the cde_val is at the start. e.g i/p ml_orig as cde_value, date_key, desc  o/p cde_vale, date_key, desc

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
regexp_replace(val,'(^|, )[a-zA-Z_]+ as ','\1')
```

Regex explanation:

Second argument of `regexp_replace` is the pattern to be matched. In this case it is

- `(^|, )` matches either the start of the string or a `,` followed by a space.
- `[a-zA-Z_]+` matches one or more times, characters in the range `a-z` or `A-Z` or an `_` (underscore)
- `[[:space:]]as` matches space followed by `as` literally.

The third argument is the replacement character(s). Here it is `\1` (meaning the first group) which means you only retain the start of string portion preceding the pattern or `,[[:space:]]`.

*Note that `[[:space:]]` was used in the explanation for clarity. Using a literal space character or `[[:space:]]` will work in a pattern match.*

In SQL context, you will be replacing all the column-name followed by a space followed by as with nothing, which i assume is what's needed.

Comment: can you please explain this syntax, how it is doing

Comment: provided some explanation of the arguments used.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select run_id, src_key, cd_key, (select regexp_replace(ml_orig,'(.)*',
run_id||','||src_key||','|| cd_key)from tablename) as cde_value, date_key, desc 
from table name;
```

sample input output:

```
SELECT * FROM D061_WORDS;
nikhil sugandh
punam sugandh
mohit sugandh
select regexp_replace(a,'(.)* {1}',','||'sugandh') from d061_WORDS;
,sugandhsugandh
,sugandhsugandh
,sugandhsugandh
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't neglect to test with the target pattern in all possible positions in the string, including not there at all.  Always expect the unexpected! This method uses 3 capture groups.  The first one is the start of the line or all characters followed by a space that occur before the second group.  The second group is one or more word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character) followed by  'as' .  The third capture group is the rest of the line.

This is replaced by the 1st and 3rd capture groups, effectively removing the word before and including 'as'.  Starts at position 1, does it for all occurrences ignoring case.

```
SQL> with tbl(id, str) as (
     select 1, 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, ml_orig as cde_value, date_key, desc' from dual union all
     select 2, 'ml_orig as cde_value, run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc' from dual union all
     select 3, 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc, ml_orig as cde_value' from dual union all
     select 4, 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc, ml_orig as cde_value' from dual union all
     select 5, 'ml_oria as run_id, ml_orib as src_key, ml_oric as desc, ml_orid as cde_value' from dual union all
     select 6, NULL from dual union all
     select 7, 'run_id,ml_orig     as   src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc, ml_orig as cde_value' from dual
   )
   select id, regexp_replace(str, '(^|.*?, *)(\w+ +as +)(.*)', '\1\3', 1, 0, 'i') fixed
   from tbl;

        ID FIXED
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 run_id, src_key, cd_key, cde_value, date_key, desc
         2 cde_value, run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc
         3 run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc, cde_value
         4 run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc, cde_value
         5 run_id, src_key, desc, cde_value
         6
         7 run_id,src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc, cde_value

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: How about this string 'run_id, src_key, cd_key, date_key, desc,ml_orig   as  cde_value  -- problem i am getting is  String is not constant it will be row in table  some  row string data will have double space before the "as" or/and after.  This regex is  not working    regexp_replace(x,'(^|, )+[a-zA-Z_]+ AS ','\1') yy for if the double space or multiple space. can you please see

Comment: Just add a '+' after the space for "one or more" in the second capture group. You should have mentioned this in your original post. I'll edit my post.

Comment: CDE_KEY,  SRC_KEY,mil_orig  AS CDE_VALUE, abc -- here there is no space after the "," comma. so can you please include this also what would be expression

Comment: Ok, I just tweaked the regex to allow for that.  It does not replace it with a space though. Note ID 7